# JSP/Servlet How to identify if the HTTP request came from an ajax request

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, struts2, request

I am using JQuery-Ajax, and History.js for my web app, is there anyway I can identify if the request came from an AJAX request or just normal request? What I aim to do is something like this

```
<%if(isRequestAjax()){%>
<jsp:include page="/views/header.jsp" />        
}
<%}%>

<div id ="profilePage>
    <!-- user profile will be loaded here !-->
</div>
```

I am also using Struts2 as may MVC framework

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to check for a request header `X-Requested-With` it will be `XMLHttpRequest`

```
  if ("XMLHttpRequest".equals(req.getHeader("X-Requested-With")) ){
           // include other file
  }
```

Comment: How? you're seems a little discrete, a definite example would be nice

Comment: no it is not. I am not sure if this header is set by all browsers/user-agents. So I will pass an additional parameter with request to identify by request classification.